# Why does my daemon (which is under root) shut down when logging out or logging in as another user?

Tags: macos, daemon, user-agent, launchd

I've developed a daemon which runs under root using "launchctl". However, after I log out and switch to another user, it stops and starts a new instance under root. I need it to launched once only on OS X startup.

Here's the plist file I use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>root</string>
    <key>WaitForDebugger</key>
    <false/>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>EnableTransactions</key>
    <false/>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/usr/local/mylogs/mylogs.log</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/usr/local/mylogs/mylogs.log</string>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.daemon.mydaemon</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Applications/MyDaemon.app/Contents/MacOS/MyDaemon</string>
    </array>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I launched the daemon using the following:

> sudo launchctl /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.daemon.mydaemon.plist

OR

> sudo launchctl /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.daemon.mydaemon.plist

Also after switching to another user I receive an error and daemon stops working but I see in Activity Monitor

> _RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer, _CGSDefaultConnection() is NULL.

Comment: Nothing stands out, I'm afraid – that looks about right. Are you sure the daemon is exiting _because_ you're logging out, rather than for some other incidental reason (can't think what)? Minor points: (i) that's `launchctl load <file>` you're using, yes? (your examples omit the `load`); (ii) don't put things in `/System/Library`, since they might be stomped on without warning in a system upgrade (`/Library` is OK).

Comment: I tried both cases. The result is the same. Also receive an error: _RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer, _CGSDefaultConnection() is NULL.

Comment: Is your daemon possibly linked against one of the non-daemon-safe frameworks (Cocoa, CoreVideo, ...)? For a complete list see section "Framework Cross Reference" on [Technical Note TN2083, Daemons and Agents](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2083).

Comment: I use Cocoa.framework which is not daemon safe according to the list. But with out it I'll have a lot of errors...

Comment: @Sergio: In this case you wrote an agent, not a daemon. Daemons have no GUI, agents may have one. From the TN above: "A daemon cannot display any GUI; more specifically, it is not allowed to connect to the window server."